# React Router shows blank page until refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frameworks, router

I'm learning React and this project involves React Router. I have read a number of tutorials but can't get them to work for my project

Basically, the issue is that my React routes work in that the URL changes and the page changes, but it changes to a blank index.html unless reloaded, where it works correctly.

My App.js renders `<Profile />` when accessToken is made:

```
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContainer>
        <GlobalStyle />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path ='/' component={withRouter(accessToken ? Profile : Login)} />
            <Route exact path ='/playlist' component={withRouter(Playlist)} />
          </Switch>
      </AppContainer>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

And `<Profile />` has the Link to `<Playlist />`:

```
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Banner user={user} />
            <Link to='/playlist'>Find New Music</Link>
            <Favorites history={history} />
        </Wrapper>
    );
```

Which is just a template right now:

```
const Playlist = () => {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

The  works, and redirects to localhost:3000/playlist, but that route displays a white screen. When refreshed, `<h1>Hello</h1>` is correctly displayed. Does anyone have an idea of why this happens?

Comment: can you try to swap the order of routes? i think I had similar thing happened to me because of the order.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: Order doesn't seem to matter and I did my best to re-create it in codesandbox (my app has a backend for Spotify OAuth which most components need so it was hollowed out) but routing worked there. My only other thought is that it might be in the backend itself, but commenting out basically line by line potential culprits like:

`app.get('*', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/public', 'index.html'));`
doesn't fix the issue.

I'm willing to post any and all code if it will help, this is just a personal project

Answer (score 1):

Found the bug.

```
useEffect(() => window.location.hash = '', []);
```

breaks routing. It was a quick fix hidden in the Profile.jsx component to a different problem and I will have to look into a better method.